# eu pequena duvida de uma mensagem no git hub

Tags: github

gente eu tenho começa a estuda git hub estou conhecente a plataforma.
depois de algum tempo testando os comandos eu deparo com isso 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

todo comendo que eu dou agora dar essa mensagem
que traduzido fica

No mestre da filial
Sua filial está atualizada com 'origem / mestre'.

Nada a comprometer, trabalhando na árvore limpa

podem me ajudar a entender isso??
obrigado pela atençao.

Comment: você está no 'branch' master.... ele está atualizado e não há nada para dar commit..... árvore de trabalho está limpa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Antes de realizar o commit, de um git status. Isso irá mostrar se existe alguma mudança e  vai dizer se tem algo para dar o commit.

Lembre que antes do commit você precisa do "git add < nome do arquivo>" ou "git add ." para adicionar todas as mudanças.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado !!